# TypeError: R[o5R.F6s] is not a function in changing states in phaser box2d

Tags: javascript, box2d, phaser

i build my game using `phaser.2.4.3.min.js` and `phaser.2.2.2.box2d.min.js`
When trying to change states this error is being raised `TypeError: R[o5R.F6s] is not a function` and i can't seem to figure out the problem

PS : i took The source code of box2d plugin from the example folder in phaser , and i did not purchase the full plugin yet i was just testing it .

is there anyway to fix this issue ?

here is the game code : http://jsfiddle.net/fbdtq1tg/5/

and here where the error is raised :

```
SetGameOver: function () {
            this.game.state.start("TheGame");
        }
```

Comment: The minified version used by the examples might be old, and since it's not actually a distribution of the library, all bets are off as to whether it will work for anything other than the examples it's used in. Why not buy the actual plugin? You can request a refund if it doesn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a [known issue](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1884) in the Box2D plugin. As much as I hate suggesting buying a library like this, they *claim* to have fixed this bug in the currently distributed version. If you're dead set on Phaser and this Box2D plugin, I would consider buying it but my honest advice would be to stay away from such libraries.

Comment: The ["known issue" you linked](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1884) seems to have been fixed in a later version, and [was caused by a user accidentally using an old version](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1884#issuecomment-117833832).

Comment: I'll reword my answer to be a little more clear, but that is exactly what I said.

Comment: so i guess if i want to continue using box2d plugin with phaser i should buy the plugin and see if it work . thank you for your answer

Comment: i copied the javascript file from this example : `http://codepen.io/jdnichollsc/pen/XbWzxY` and the error is gone now and everything work fine